# Most Active Contributors Quarterly Report - 4th Quarter 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors

## Welcome to the first Quarterly edition of the Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

While similar to the monthly report, this report differs in that it contains fewer sections but lists the top 10 users (instead of 5) in each of those sections.

This report will be published after each calendar year quarter. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for 4th Quarter 2017

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Quarterly Reputation Leader Board
3. Quarterly Most Active Editors Award
4. Quarterly Most Active Voters Award
5. Quarterly Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Quarterly Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Quarterly Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Quarterly Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Quarterly Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Quarterly Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Ranked 1st Summary List
12. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    1,020
2   Monomeeth                  680
3   grgarside                  610
4   bmike                      290
5   patrix                     230
6   oa-                        180
7   JMY1000                    170
8   fsb                        130
9   Scot                       120
10  Mark, dwightk               90
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 1,950.

---

[image: TITLE: QUARTERLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]

You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/46/quarter/apple/2017-10-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   grgarside                290
2   Allan                    264
3   bmike                    262
4   klanomath, oa-           250
5   patrix                   144
6   Monomeeth                115
7   IconDaemon                98
8   user3439894               79
9   Tetsujin                  54
10  JMY1000                   22
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth               1,652
2   LangLangC               1,236
3   PeterJ                    809
4   bmike                     675
5   JW8                       592
6   grgarside                 529
7   Melvin Jefferson          413
8   patrix                    335
9   Citizen                   325
10  creidhne                  234
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    202
2   fsb                      142
3   patrix                   132
4   IconDaemon               112
5   Scot                     107
6   grgarside, Mark           93
7   pjc90                     84
8   Monomeeth                 78
9   oa-                       66
10  bjbk                      19
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   JMY1000                  553
2   patrix                   241
3   Monomeeth                235
4   grgarside                222
5   oa-                      188
6   Scot                     174
7   Allan                    172
8   fsb                      171
9   pjc90                    165
10  IconDaemon               107
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    331
2   JMY1000                  107
3   grgarside                 80
4   Scot                      69
5   pjc90                     48
6   IconDaemon                39
7   fsb                       37
8   Glorfindel                33
9   Mark                      27
10  LangLangC                 20
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    110
2   fsb                       95
3   JMY1000                   65
4   IconDaemon                53
5   Scot                      48
6   Tetsujin                  42
7   grgarside                 29
8   pjc90                     27
9   Mark                      20
10  bjbk                      15
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    42
2   patrix                   23
3   fsb                      17
4   Tetsujin                 16   
5   Mark                     15
6   oa-, Scot, pjc90         12
7   grgarside, Glorfindel    11
8   IconDaemon               10
9   Monomeeth                 9
10  bjbk                      8
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   techraf                 199
2   Allan                   113
3   grgarside                68
4   JMY1000                  62
5   patrix                   52
6   fsb                      51
7   oa-                      41
8   Monomeeth                40
9   Glorfindel               39
10  pjc90                    38
```

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [JMY1000](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/140612/jmy1000)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Techraf](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/145449/techraf)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In the 4th Quarter of 2017 our [Moderators](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 1,470 flags with an average handling time of 13 minutes. In summary, we:

- deleted 688 comments
- deleted 929 posts
- closed 554 posts
- edited 791 posts
- created 514 posts
- created 1,397 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)